# Google maps markers to manipulate dom

Tags: jquery, dom, maps, markers

Is it possible to use google markers to manipulate dom parts in a webpage outside of a map instead of using infowindows or the like? Like setting an id to each marker and then using jquery to assign click events to the marker to manipulate other parts of my web page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you can, but i suggest looking into Gmaps js, its less pain and code -- https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/ -- here is a demo with just plain gmap and a click function --http://jsfiddle.net/gdcpodck/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the event listener as per the standard from the api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker[count], 'click', (function() {
   //should be able to do what you want inside here. 
})
```